# User testing, simple flow testing

Tags: usability, usability-testing, qualitative-analysis, test

I am going to run a user testing for a bank in order to evaluate ''be our customer'' flow. Which starts with collecting basic information then connecting with a representative to finalise the application. The flow is very simple, it has only one CTA for each screen and dropdown selection & basic input text fields to collect information, hence I believe task completion rate etc is not right criteria to focus. I would like to investigate how the logic of questions to collect basic information laid on the flow and how confident the user to give information on that flow to be a customer.
What type of methods you would do?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are basically testing for motivation and how the logic of the questions matches up with the mental models of the users, a basic paper form will still do the job.

An higher fidelity of this approach will be to use a basic HTML form and then install Hotjar to do a form field analysis. The insights this will give you include "time spent on field", "blankout rates" e.t.c

Visit here for more data points Hotjar offers: https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/sections/115002610667-Forms

Answer (score 1):

During each in-person usability session I'd encourage the tester to think out loud, so that you gain both insight into their immediate impression and understanding of each page, as well as their thought patterns and realisations as they go through the motions.

Answer (score 0):

**"be our customer"** - **the account creation process** itself or the use of the service - can have a comprehensive client decision-making process:

- reference?
- advertisement?
- economic considerations?
- brand?

I think it's worth focusing on **quality** in this case. Suppose there are 60-70 banks - why did the customer choose this particular one?

The possible methods are:

(source:https://www.questionpro.com/blog/qualitative-research-methods/#Qualitative_Research_Methods_with_Examples)

1. One-on-One interview
2. Focus groups
3. Record keeping
4. Process of observation